# The browser tells "failed to compile"

Tags: css, vue.js, postcss

i import the bootstrap vue like this:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
```

i already tried consulting all forums with similar questions but nothing

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

```
Failed to compile.

/home/fabry/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-oneOf-3-2!/home/fabry/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: No PostCSS Config found in: /home/fabry/node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist
    at config.search.then (/home/fabry/Scrivania/programmazione/web/Vue/realVueFool/quiz/node_modules/postcss-load-config/src/index.js:91:15)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the [instructions here](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/)?

It sounds like you either didn't install all the dependencies or failed to register components in your Vue app.

Comment: thank you, solved by reinstalling the dependecies of: vue, boostrap-vue adn bootstrap, have a nice day.